# Transaction error: Error while committing the transaction

Tags: java, database, hibernate, maven, transactions

I making an application in which I have to work with multiple databases making CRUD operations for databases. But i have encountered this problem and i don't have any clue about what could be wrong. It's strange because a few time ago worked properly and now gives me the same error. Please help!

In the past it worked, and now no strange think because i didn't modified the application at all. This is for pgAdmin server working with maven-hibernate project.

I have this problem only when i wanna update something. I wanna mention that i have a connection for every database not one for all.

```
public boolean executeTransaction(Consumer<EntityManager> action) {
        EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        try {
            entityTransaction.begin();
            action.accept(entityManager);
            entityTransaction.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.err.println("Transaction error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            entityTransaction.rollback();<<-- at this line everything breaks.
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


Transaction error: Error while committing the transaction

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active


    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:103)

    at helper.DatabaseHelper.executeTransaction(DatabaseHelper.java:42)

    at daoImpl.PasariDao.update(PasariDao.java:43)

    at main.Menu.pasariOperations(Menu.java:240)

    at main.Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

When i wanna make update operation this is the error i get.
It should print what i have in the database before the update and after...

Comment: What does your `Consumer<EntityManager> action` do with the `entityManager`?

Comment: please call e.printStackTrace() and post the stacktrace you get.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer , it's used to interact with the persistence context.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, now i got something else :https://ibb.co/9WRKHLD, here u can see a picture with the errors.

Comment: Do you have any PreUpdate or PostUpdate Event Listeners?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, no.

Comment: And what did change since it worked?

Comment: Well this is the strange part, i haven't done nothing.

Comment: Why do you do the transaction management manually?

Comment: Our lab teacher gave us this project from scratches to finish the homework on in so i'm not sure why the transaction is done manually...